# Why Firefox won't start Css without errors message?

Tags: html, css, debugging, firefox

I write this sample code on notepad for an html site with css but this won't work on Mozilla(version49.0.etc) while it does on IE, Chrome and Opera. If i start it on FF, debugger says "CSS has no errors" but it only display html code. 
Someone know how to fix it?

Here there are the codes(html and CSS) of my site on local path:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd>
    <html lang="it">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="iso-8859-1">

        <title>Site</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <link href="C:/Users/Dean/Desktop/Site/File/file1.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


</head>



<body class="sub">
<div class="alt">


<h1>Text here</h1>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here there is the CSS file properties:

```
.sub{background-image:url("../image/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;

}


.alt {background-color:hotpink;
    box-align:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    }

.set {font-size:12px;
    color:white;
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing to prevent the page from working in Firefox just tested and it works. But there is a missing closing bracket } from the .set-class. Also I box-align is obsolete css-value.

Comment: So what you think about my problem? I thought it could be some like css permission which i don't do after installing. Do you want some pic of my FF view? Thanks for the closing bracket ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it is because your stylesheet is linked via the non standard `file` protocol (`href="C:/Users/Dean/Desktop/Site/File/file1.css"`). From my experience, Firefox usually complies to standards more than other browsers.

I'm *assuming* this is why your example works in other browsers, but not in FF. Try serving your stylesheet using an HTTP server.

Comment: Or simply changing the path to a root- or page-relative URL (i.e. `href="./file/file1.css"` or similar)

Comment: After a time i solved changhing CSS rules to relative path and it works so this question is solved. Thanks all for answers